# How to use set method in a loop? (Java)

Tags: java, loops, oop, arraylist

I am beginner and wondering how should I use the loop to update the attribute in an ArrayList of objects. So here I have an arraylist of smartphones and each of them has serialNo and brand as the attribute, but the price has not yet been updated.

```
public class Smartphone{
  public String serialNo;
  public String brand;
  public Double price;

  public Smartphone(String serialNo, String brand){
    this.serialNo = serialNo;
    this.brand = brand;
  }

  public void setPrice(double price){
    this.price = price;
  }

}

public class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    ArrayList<Smartphone> smartphones = new ArrayList<Smartphone>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      Smartphone s = new Smartphone("12345678" ,"Samsung");
      smartphones.add(s);
    }


    //later I realize I want to add the price, 
    //but it seems the loop I'm using is not working
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      smartphones.get(i).setPrice(398);
    }

  }
}
```

I wonder why the loop that I am using is not working, Is there any other way to add price to each of the smartphones?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? I mean how do you know that is not working.

Comment: your setting of price is working,  if you start printing the prices, you will see that it is printing the right values for each smartphone in the list

Comment: Just add next to the `setPrice` line a `System.out.println(smartphones.get(i));`, you might want to override `Smartphone.toString()` to get something usefull ;)

Comment: To make it more beginner friendly just make it `System.out.println(smartphones.get(i).price);`

Comment: Why does the class use the `Double` wrapper class?

Comment: @AxelH It uses the memory more than 8 times than the primitive.

Comment: Here, a small [ideone](http://ideone.com/kN2PQX) of your code. @Midnightas, don't have the Byte in mind but ... So ? That's not a problem of memory or performance, if he need a null value ?

Comment: Using wrappers (which are objects) makes it need allocation, deallocation, memory management and getters/setters. And plus the boxing makes it even slower.

Comment: @Midnightas but that's not the point here !

Comment: @AxelH I didn't say it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested with the below code on AIDE. Your code works fine.

Note my use of an enhanced for-loop to display the prices. If you don't explicitly need an index inside the loop, an enhanced for-loop is a clean way of iterating over a list.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Smartphone{
    public String serialNo;
    public String brand;
    public Double price;

    public Smartphone(String serialNo, String brand){
        this.serialNo = serialNo;
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price){
        this.price = price;
    }

}

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        ArrayList<Smartphone> smartphones = new ArrayList<Smartphone>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            Smartphone s = new Smartphone("12345678" ,"Samsung");
            smartphones.add(s);
        }


        //later I realize I want to add the price, 
        //but it seems the loop I'm using is not working
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            smartphones.get(i).setPrice(398);
        }

        // Display prices to ensure they were set
        for (Smartphone phone : smartphones) {
            System.out.println(phone.price);

        }

    }
}
```

Excuse the odd indentation. AIDE likes to play fast and loose with indenting characters.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative loop suggestions. Your code runs successfully.

Answer (score -1):

Your code seemed to be working for me, however if you mean that it isn't working because you can't see the prices then all you need to do is create a function inside of your smartphone class that returns `this.price` and call it after after you use `smartphones.get(i).setPrice(398);`.